# Error 426 Upgrade required with REST API - PUT method

Tags: rest, put

I am trying to update one of the table using REST API call with the PUT method which is running on my linux server(centos).

Here am sending headers(authorization,accept:"text/csv") with the body having values.

when am hitting with this payload to the linux server am getting **"ERROR : 426 with UPGRADE_REQUIRED"**

All the above steps am doing with POSTMAN

Please guide on this.

Regards,
navaneeth

Comment: https://<domain>:1234/admin/tables/tabelid/values

Comment: Below response with 426 Error Code   {
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "code": "UPGRADE_REQUIRED",
        "errorFields": [],
        "messages": [],
        "invalidFields": []
    }
}

Comment: And also am getting below message from server message "The client should switch to a different protocol such as TLS/1.0."  am doing through postman."

Comment: Have you tried invoking the service as http ?